# How to make mpv have the slider when playing an audio file

Tags: debian, audio, multimedia, mpv

I wanna have controls just like I have when playing a video file in mpv. Is there a way to do it ?

I tried for e.g.

```
$ mpv --fullscreen music.mp3
```

but didn't get anything which works.

I even tried `mpv --list-options` to see if there is something that I missed but came up empty.

Looking forward for guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is

```
$ mpv --force-window $file.mp3
```

I have just taken .mp3 an an example filetype or format type and $file for an example file. Just put the filename and the filetype as it is instead of the fictious example shared above.

Comment: I dunno how many times I have come for this.